# recursive Stored procedure or function

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

is there any way to have a stored procedure or function like below c# code:

I want to convert this method to T-SQL.

```
public static IEnumerable<String> GetWords(Int32 length)
{
  if ( length <= 0 ) yield break ;

  for (Char c = '!'; c <= '~'; c++)
  {
    if ( length > 1 )
    {
      foreach ( String restWord in GetWords( length - 1 ) )
        yield return c + restWord;
    }
    else
      yield return "" + c;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. For more information about the use of the `yield` keyword in methods, refer to the MSDN entry (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx).

Comment: the method create all possible string with specific length.i want to write a tsql that reate all possible string with specific length like the c# method

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by that. What is your question?

Comment: i want to convert this c# code to sql server t-sql

Comment: In general. the SQLish way to do this would be to generate the set of all words of length `x` (for all reasonable lengths of `x` that you would intend to use this function for) and store all of the results in a table. Then you'd just query this table when you need the result. There's no need to regenerate this set of answers each time - it's a static set of results.

Comment: please explain me more info about  your comment

Comment: Leave it in C# and call it from sql-server.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You do realize, don't you that what you're doing is essentially generating a sequence of base-94 numbers...and the domain of the strings you're generating gets vary large, very quickly. For instance, using your character set (0x21–0x7E), there are

- 8,836 possible (94<sup>2</sup>) 2-character strings
- 830,584 possible (94<sup>3</sup>) 3-character strings
- 78,074,896 possible (94<sup>4</sup>) 4-character strings
- etc.
- By the time you've hit 6 characters, your looking at 94<sup>6</sup>, or 689,869,781,056 strings to generate.

So, if you're going to do this, create a [SQL Server CLR table-valued function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131103.aspx) to generate them on the fly.

The way you're building your strings is likely to be ... a little hard on the ol' heap and string intern table. For starters, I'd mark the assembly to not do string interning via the assembly attribute [`CompilationRelaxationsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilationrelaxationsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

And use a non-recursive approach that uses a single fixed-size `StringBuilder`. Here's a SQL Server table-valued function that does what your code does (I think) using that approach:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

class MySqlServerDotNetFunctions
{

  [SqlFunction( TableDefinition="id int not null , value varchar(2000)" , FillRowMethodName="FillRow")]
  public static IEnumerable<Tuple<long,StringBuilder>> GenerateStrings( int stringLength )
  {
    const char lowerBound  = '!' ;
    const char upperBound = '~' ;
    if ( stringLength < 1 || stringLength > 2000 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("stringLength","string length must be in the range 1-2000" ) ;

    // initialize the stringbuilder
    bool          carry = false ; // carry flag
    StringBuilder sb    = new StringBuilder(new string(lowerBound,stringLength)) ;
    for ( long i = 0 ; !carry && ++i > 0 ; )
    {
      // return the current iteration
      yield return new Tuple<long,StringBuilder>(i,sb) ;

      // increment our string
      int  p     = sb.Length-1 ; // we work right-to-left
      do
      {
        carry = ++sb[p] > upperBound   ;
        if ( carry )
        {
          sb[p] = lowerBound ;
        }
      } while ( carry && --p >= 0 ) ;

    }
  }

  public static void FillRow( object o , out long id , out string value )
  {
    Tuple<long,StringBuilder> item = (Tuple<long,StringBuilder>) o ;

    id    = item.Item1            ;
    value = item.Item2.ToString() ;
    return ;
  }

}
```